# Rails blog tutorial 4.3 ProgramError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I'm attempting to follow the rails tutorial for creating a blog [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html). I'm on step 4.3, but after adding `root 'welcome#index'` to my roots.rb file, I get an error page telling me this:

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

[image: Photo of error]

Comment: check your stylesheets for syntax errors. (if you're using sass)

Comment: Should that be `"data-turbolinks-track" => true`, rather than `"data-turbolinks-track": true`? I'll post as an answer (with explanation)  if it solves your issue.

Comment: Or, try replacing `'application'` on that line, with `'defaults'`? This could be the solution if you have a version compatibility issue.

Comment: @tom changing both occurences of 'application' to 'defaults' solved my problem, thanks! What was my issue and how did this fix it?

Comment: Actually upon further research -- while this works, it's not the correct answer at all. See my answer below...

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in Windows (which I can see you are, given the screen-shot in your post!), `coffee-script-source` version >= `1.9.0` does not work.

You can change it to a previous version adding this line to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
```

And then to resolve dependencies correctly, run:

```
bundle update coffee-script-source
```

If you google this error, you will find other people talking about replacing  `'application'` to `'defaults'` -- however, this is misleading. Doing this merely prevents the app from finding the appropriate `JS` and `CSS` files. (You'd be better off deleting the line of code!)

To get the app to find and execute `application.js` without error, on Windows, you must downgrade `coffee-script-source`. (Alternatively of course, you can use a `Linux` operating system for development; something I'd highly recommend!)

[Here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/24084) is the relevant issue, raised in GitHub.